# Angular 9 $localize not working with --configuration=de

Tags: angular, localization, internationalization, angular9

When using $localize from "@angular/localize/" with "**ng serve --configuration=de**" i get this: 
[image: $localize not defined]

It works perfect when running the project with just "**ng serve**".

in app.component.ts

```
public product: TabDefinition = { name: $localize`Products`, route: "/products" };
```

in Polyfills.ts

```
import "@angular/localize/init";
import { loadTranslations } from "@angular/localize";

loadTranslations({
    "6707361102856436710": "Produkte",
  });
```

Comment: Please give a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

What i have done is make a `TranslationComponent`, as long as you specify the id in the template and in the `$localize` call it will map correctly

```
<p i18n="@@pending-changes">You have unsaved changes are you sure you want to navigate?</p>
```

```
return confirm($localize`:@@pending-changes:You have unsaved changes are you sure you want to navigate?`);
```

```
   <trans-unit id="pending-changes" datatype="html">
        <source>You have unsaved changes are you sure you want to navigate?</source>
        <target state="translated">Vous avez des modifications non enregistrées, êtes-vous sûr de vouloir naviguer?</target>
        <context-group purpose="location">
          <context context-type="sourcefile">src/app/shared/component/translations/translations.component.html</context>
          <context context-type="linenumber">1</context>
        </context-group>
      </trans-unit>
```

Cheers

[image]

Comment: This woks only if you do not have your string like $localize`:@@pending-changes:You have ${changesCount} unsaved changes are you sure you want to navigate?`

It than create `{$PH}` placeholder I cannot workaround. I feel hopeless.

Comment: Agreed with @petriq. this is not a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add this

```
import '@angular/localize/init';
```

to your polyfills.ts file?

Maybe there is path problem. 
Try this:

```
import '../node_modules/@angular/localize/init';
```

Comment: @PanayotZhaltov did you see my comment... also you can follow the repo on gt for updates

https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/32912#issuecomment-614405330